# hyperlink to another worksheet in Numbers 09

Tags: numbers

Is it possible to hyperlink to another sheet in the same workbook in Numbers '09? I want to have a link so I can jump back and fourth between sheets. Excel has this feature but I can't find anything about it in Numbers. It appears that Numbers only allows hyperlinks to webpages or to send an email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short (and sad) answer is: No, unfortunately it is not possible.